# Request Wrapper Body using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have two entities that represent two tables in the database, similar to the concept of inheritance:

Entity Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="person", schema = "myself")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "person_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    @NotNull(message = "name_expects")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private AdressPerson adressPerson;

... get and setters
}
```

Entity Adress:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="adress_person", schema = "myself")
public class AdressPerson implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "adress", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String adress;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Person person;

... get and setters
}
```

I need to send a single request post and form-data with this:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"John Doe",
   "type": "home",
   "adress" : "Madison Ave"
}
```

In my controller I need to receive this way:

```
...
@PostMapping(value = "", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public AdressPerson addAdressPerson(@NotNull @RequestParam AdressPerson adressPersonRequest)  {
    //code
}
...
```

However I am not able to do the mapping, I have tried to use filter and RequestWrapper, but I was not able to overwrite the message body. Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `@RequestParam` maps query parameters, like `?name=something&address=some-address`

While you're trying to make a POST request and want to deserialize JSON request payload into a java class.

Use `@RequestBody` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Within your @RestController class you can define your POST mapping method as follows:

```
...
@PostMapping(value = "")
public AdressPerson addPerson(@RequestBody Person person)  {
       //code
}
...
```

As a default, your spring-boot project expects / returns a JSON body, so you can omit the consumes and produces attributes.

Now for receiving the payload in above controller, your JSON request body should look like  -

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"John Doe",
  adressPerson": {
      "type": "home",
      "adress" : "Madison Ave"
   }
}
```

Also, within your entity Person, remove @JsonIgnore from adressPerson field, instead try using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now another question: what if I need, for example, to send in a single request more models than the example I posted?

Comment: For such a scenario, first create the API contract i.e. your JSON payload and REST endpoint nomenclature. Once your JSOn payload takes the final shape, mimic the same in the form of Request DTO...and within your controller method accept this request DTO with @RequestBody annotation as an argument. Do let me know if this helps resolve your query.

Comment: Also, if the above answer helped you, request you to upvote and accept. :)

Comment: I did what you suggested I do, switched to RequestBody and it's giving an error now, "Unsupported Media Type".

Comment: I am assuming you are using Postman REST client. So while passing in your request body, select application/json where it says text in the dropdown.